# Download excel file with format intact using action button in r shiny

Tags: r, shiny, download

I have created the following shiny App

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(openxlsx)
```

Once we import the packages, we create the ui and server as follows

```
ui <- fluidPage(
fileInput(inputId = "file", label = "Read File Here", accept = c(".xlsx")),
useShinyjs(), actionButton("showtxt", "Show/Download File"))


server <- function(input, output, session){
server <- function(input, output, session){
observeEvent(input$showtxt,{
tf<-tempdir()
infile<- input$file
wb2 <-openxlsx::loadWorkbook(file = infile$datapath)
df_1<-data.frame("DF"= c(1:3))      
addWorksheet(wb = wb2,sheetName =  "Parameters1")
writeData(wb2, "Parameters1", df_1, startCol = 1, startRow = 2, rowNames = TRUE)
saveWorkbook(wb2, "File.xlsx") })
# Call Onclick
 onclick("showtxt", runjs("window.open('test.xlsx')"))}
  shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

The code works by creating a clone/ copy of the excel workbook uploaded. When the download is pressed, the new excel workbook will have all the formats of the original workbook along with a new sheet added.
This new workbook is saved in the folder containing the script. How can I make it go to my laptops download folder by default.
Note: I have tried this with a download handler but for some reasons, I would like to use an action button.
I request someone to take a look and guide me here. thank you in advance.

Comment: This is a setting of the browser.

Comment: why is it import for you to use the action button and not the download handler?